# Key Error when loading Matlab file into python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

So I have 32 Matlab files that are approximately 1.2 GB Each. I load them all in the same way (as shown below). I get all the values from the row named 'data_mat' This has worked but when I get to person 27 it errors out giving a key error and saying 'data_mat'

KeyError: 'data_mat'
But I know 'data_mat' exists because I have checked and sometimes person 27 will run with no problem other times it gives me this error. For this person, it errors out more times than not but it seems like the same is happening for every file after 27 to 32 as well. Where sometimes it will work and sometimes it will give me this error.

Below are some examples of how I load these files in and run them in the main class.

```
class Channels():
def __init__(self):
    self = self

def all(self, i, c):

    if i == 1:
        # Value error: need to double-check correct columns labeling for the classification of each sleep/dream wake cycle
        a = hdf5storage.loadmat("Sub1.mat")
        b = a['data_mat']
        person1 = pd.DataFrame(b[c])
        person1.columns = ["Dream + Recall(NREM)","Dream + Recall(NREM)", "No Experience(NREM)", "No Experience(NREM)", "No Experience(NREM)", "Dream + Recall(NREM)", "Dream + Recall(REM)","Dream + Recall(NREM)", "Dream + Recall(NREM)"]
        #person1.columns = ["Dream + Recall(NREM)","Dream + Recall(NREM)", "No Experience(NREM)", "No Experience(NREM)", "No Experience(NREM)", "Dream + Recall(NREM)", "Dream + Recall(REM)","Dream + Recall(NREM)", "Dream + Recall(NREM)", "Dream + Recall(REM)"]
        return person1

    elif i == 2:
        a = spio.loadmat("Sub2.mat")
        b = a['data_mat']
        person2 = pd.DataFrame(b[c])
        person2.columns = ["Dream - Recall(NREM)", "Dream - Recall(NREM)", "Dream - Recall(NREM)", "No Experience(NREM)", "Dream + Recall(NREM)", "No Experience(NREM)", "Dream - Recall(NREM)", "Dream - Recall(NREM)", "Dream + Recall(REM)", "Dream - Recall(NREM)", "Dream + Recall(NREM)", "Dream + Recall(NREM)"]
        return person2

    elif i == 27:
        #v7.3 HDF
        a = hdf5storage.loadmat("Sub27.mat")
        b = a['data_mat']
        person27= pd.DataFrame(b[c])
        person27.columns = ["Dream - Recall(NREM)","Dream + Recall(NREM)","Dream - Recall(NREM)","Dream + Recall(NREM)","Dream - Recall(NREM)","Dream + Recall(NREM)","Dream + Recall(NREM)","Dream + Recall(NREM)","Dream + Recall(REM)","Dream + Recall(NREM)","Dream + Recall(NREM)", "Dream - Recall(REM)", "Dream + Recall(NREM)","Dream + Recall(REM)"]
        return person27 

main():

person = Channels().all(27, 0)
```

If possible I don't want to change how I load in the files because I know they work for most of my people. But how I can fix this so I stop getting this key error sometimes and all of it just runs smoothly?

Extra Notes: I never modify the file I just extract data from it, when loading it a is a type dict and b is a type numpy array and person is a pandas data frame.

Please help, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Does this happen when you load the files in sequence? in a particular order? or for a particular file (whether loaded in sequence or individually)?  Is the problem with a `spio` format or `hdf5storage`?  I assume the `spio` is a scipy.io` load.  I'm not familiar `hdf5storage`, but assume it's a third party one that can work with the new `HDF5` files.

Comment: I'm trying to determine whether it's a problem with a particular file, or (indirectly) a memory error.  You obviously haven't provided us with the information needed to reproduce the error.  So the best we can do is suggest ways of getting to the root of the problem.

Comment: Yes I only get this error when loading it after all the other 26 files

Comment: But I do believe it is with hdf5storage because that is how I am loading this file in

Comment: I believe it is a memory error, is there any way I can fix that though and work around it?